# Need help setting up virtual isolated network with 2 VMs

Tags: security, virtualization, malware

Good afternoon.  I've been searching everywhere for about an hour and I can't seem to figure this out.  I'm currently in school learning about malware analysis, so I'm wanting to set up a secure way to test it.

What I want is a virtual isolated network so that my Kali VM (analysis machine) can connect with my Windows 7 VM (victim machine), and vice versa.  So, I want these VMs to connect to each other but have NO internet connectivity.  I've tried setting up both VMs with an internal network, but I still can't seem to get them to work.  Any suggestions?  Afterwards I want to set my VMs with static IPs.

From my understanding, I don't want a Host-only network because I don't want any connectivity with the host, and I don't want a NAT connection because my VMs couldn't connect with each other (I think)

Thanks so much!

*EDIT* My main resource for this is this [website](https://blog.christophetd.fr/malware-analysis-lab-with-virtualbox-inetsim-and-burp/), but can't seem to get it working due to only having the ETH0 interface.

Comment: Your source is correct in that you need the  Internal Network adapter setting. In the commands where it lists enp0s3 just substitute it with eth0.

Comment: What hypervisor?